# how to use jquery file upload with ember browserify

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, file-upload

I'm trying to use jquery file upload with ember-cli using the npm package 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/blueimp-file-upload

and ember browserify.

I installed ember-browserify and blueimp-file-upload:

```
$ npm install --save-dev ember-browserify
$ npm install --save-dev blueimp-file-upload
```

Importing fileupload like so:

```
import fileupload from 'npm:blueimp-file-upload';
```

Gave me this error:
    Cannot find module 'jquery' from '/Users/tony/src/myapp/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor’

So I installed jquery via npm as well:

```
$ npm install --save-dev jquery
```

Now I just get this error when trying to use fileupload:

```
$(...).fileupload is not a function
```

Is there a better way to use jquery-fileupload with ember-cli?

Comment: Correct script order: `jQuery`, `jQuery-UI` and lastly `jQuery-fileupload`. Can you verify this?

Comment: yep installed jquery-ui as well.....

Comment: @freedrull were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @dzm I actually switched to using ember file uploader, sorry

Comment: You have imported jQuery plugin as `fileupload` so you can not use it as jQuery extension. I don't have idea how to import this correctly via browserify but you can use bower to import (not recommended) vendor or put files into vendor directory and import in ember-cli or find proper ember module.

Answer (score -1):

First, there is a [few plugins](https://emberobserver.com/categories/file-upload) for ember that provide you with a ready-to-use solution. If I remember right, one of them utilizes blueimp file upload. You may use one of them or look how they use underlying jquery plugins.

You may also try to install jquery-ui-widget and blueimp-file-upload via bower.

And finally, [you may write your own file uploader](http://blog.gennady.pp.ua/how-to-upload-files-with-ember-js-creating-your-own-uploader/) without using 3rd-party jquery plugins.

Comment: I don't think any of those libraries blueimp file upload except for ember-jquery-fileupload...which hasn't been updated in a year.